# How to get the first record of each type in sequence?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Table Data:

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | A |
| 6 | B |
| 7 | B |
| 8 | A |
| 9 | A |
| 10 | A |

How to get only rows with IDs `1,3,4,6,8`, or the first records on type-change by single query?

We were doing this in code using multiple queries and extensive processing especially for large data, is there a way to do this in a single query?

Comment: You can use lag() window function since 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LAG()` window function to get for every row the previous row's `type` and compare it to the current `type`.
Create a flag column that is `true` if the 2 `type`s are different and use it to filter the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, type <> LAG(type, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY id) flag
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE flag;
```

I assume that the column `type` does not contain empty values (`null`s or
empty strings).

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7i7QgGmD).

Comment: Unfortunately the `LAG` function and `WITH` are not supported in our current version of `MySql`.

Comment: @TiyebM check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/g-MqHUYk

Comment: That works! Thank you very much, please update your answer with this alternative approach.